# Laravel unit tests - changing a config value depending on test method

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

I have an application with a system to verify accounts (register -> get email with link to activate -> account verified). That verification flow is optional and can be switched off with a configuration value:

```
// config/auth.php
return [
  // ...
  'enable_verification' => true
];
```

I want to test the registration controller:

- it should redirect to home page in both cases
- when verification is ON, home page should show message 'email sent'
- when verification is OFF, home page should show message 'account created'
- etc.

My test methods:

```
public function test_UserProperlyCreated_WithVerificationDisabled()
{
    $this->app['config']->set('auth.verification.enabled', false);

    $this
        ->visit(route('frontend.auth.register.form'))
        ->type('Test', 'name')
        ->type('test@example.com', 'email')
        ->type('123123', 'password')
        ->type('123123', 'password_confirmation')
        ->press('Register');

    $this
        ->seePageIs('/')
        ->see(trans('auth.registration.complete'));
}

public function test_UserProperlyCreated_WithVerificationEnabled()
{
    $this->app['config']->set('auth.verification.enabled', true);

    $this
        ->visit(route('frontend.auth.register.form'))
        ->type('Test', 'name')
        ->type('test@example.com', 'email')
        ->type('123123', 'password')
        ->type('123123', 'password_confirmation')
        ->press('Register');

    $this
        ->seePageIs('/')
        ->see(trans('auth.registration.needs_verification'));
}
```

When debugging, I noticed that the configuration value when inside the controller method is always set to the value in the config file, no matter what I set with my `$this->app['config']->set...`

I have other tests on the user repository itself to check that it works both when validation is ON or OFF. And there the tests behave as expected.

**Any idea why it fails for controllers and how to fix that?**

Answer (score 29):

If I understand your question right - you looking for "how to set config param", then you can use `Config::set($key, $value)`

Comment: If you feel more comfortable with helpers or you are using Lumen you could also do `config()->set($key, $value)`

Comment: If you use `Config::set($key, $value)`, then you'll need to import `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config`, but this still works in Lumen as does @suarsenegger's answer.

Comment: I believe this is removed in later versions (8+) of Laravel, making the config immutable, so this approach may not continue to be supported.

Comment: I know it works still in 8. Hoping they didn't get rid of it in later versions :)

Comment: Is there an easy way to set the config back to its original state, or do I have to take care of it by hand?

Answer (score 12):

Correct answer is above

```
Config::set($key, $value)
```

Example

```
//Not forget to add namespace using class.
use Config;

//Example to set config. (configFile.key)
Config::set('auth.enable_verification', false);
```